# In Event Sourcing using SQL database as persistence, can we manage versioning events by creating a separate table for each version?

Tags: software-design, event-sourcing

I have been learning up on the concept of Event Sourcing every now and again (just through YouTube and freely available blogs and so on), and the question just popped up as I was simulating implementing it in my head. To give some context of what I was simulating:

## Example Problem:

Imagine a hotel reservation system used by the front desk and hotel managers, where they can make reservations for rooms, block rooms (for maintenance, etc.), and adjust the number of rooms available.

Example events include:

- ReservationDetailsSubmitted
- ReservationStayShortened
- ReservationStayExtended
- ReservationCheckedIn
- ReservationCheckedOut
- RoomClosedForMaintenance
- RoomClosedForCleaning
- AvailabilityAdjusted

...and so on.

The read models involved at the moment are:

- Reservation
- Allocation (for blocking in the calendar)
- RoomStatus
- RoomTypeAvailability

...where `RoomTypeAvailability` is the availability for each room type on each date. For example, Standard Room has 5 rooms available on 2023-05-01.

## Trying to Provide a Solution:

As far as I understand, events in Event Sourcing are generally categorized using some kind of `stream_id`, and the schema is usually something like below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events
(
    id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    stream_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    version   BIGINT NOT NULL,
    data      JSONB  NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (stream_id, version)
);
```

So for `Reservation...` events, the `stream_id` would naturally be the reservation code/identifier. For the `Room...` ones, the `stream_id` would be the room number/identifier. The `AvailabilityAdjusted` one is where I'm a bit stumped. Which is more appropriate for the `stream_id`? The room type identifier or the date? Is it supposed to be both? Is there a performance issue to filter the events based on the JSON data?

What if instead of the schema above (which stores the event data as JSON), we strongly type the events in the database? For `AvailabilityAdjusted`, it might be something like below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AvailabilityAdjustedEvents
(
    id                INT PRIMARY KEY,
    room_id           INT NOT NULL,
    date              DATEONLY NOT NULL,
    timestamp         DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,
    rooms_available   INT NOT NULL
);
```

Which allows indexing on the relevant columns and such. If we need to change the event schema, we create another table (maybe named `AvailabilityAdjustedEvents_20240101`), and when constructing the read model, the read model builder will need to know of both tables' existence.

## The Question:

**Bringing back the focus to "Can we create a new table for each new version of an event?"**, one immediately obvious trade off for me here would be that the read model builder will need to know about more tables, which could mean significantly more hassle to maintain (maybe?). Let's say if I'm willing to take that trade to get the ability to index the data, **the question is**:

Is there any other significant trade offs that I'm should be aware of here? Or was I mistaken in certain assumptions made above, explicitly or otherwise?

**NOTE:** I've tried Googling to see if anyone talked or discussed about something like this, but I couldn't really find any. Do let me know if there are already existing talks or discussions that I missed.

Comment: I believe your question is not about tables but about design. Stream boundary is a consistency boundary, and you need to identify some sort of domain concept (availability). From my experience with a similar domain, you have one object per room (or room type) per day. The object isn't just about availability but also about price, scheduled maintenance, and maybe other things, as they are usually related. Price can be an object of its own, but also per room per day.

Comment: Thanks for writing, @AlexeyZimarev. Hmm... I'm not sure if that addresses the question I'm asking. I'm aware that the domain concept of "availability" is required (I mentioned RoomTypeAvailability as a read model). I do know about other possible aspects like price, mix/max stay, etc., it just wasn't the point I wanted to focus on. (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued from previous comment) My question is whether there are any other trade offs I should be aware of if I create a new table for each new version of the event. The example problem I provided was just to give some context/basis to illustrate on. I'll try to edit the question to further clarify that. I hope I didn't just completely misunderstand your point. Apologies if I did.

Comment: That's why I commented instead of writing it as an answer. Once more, think about event streams (not tables, but a stream with an id) as a consistency boundary, similar to what in DDD we call an Aggregate. A stream is where you ensure that your domain object is internally consistent. If that becomes clear, you first won't consider creating a table per event type as it will be meaningless. The second part to create a table per event type _and_ version will be even less relevant. Btw what you don't have in your table is the event type, I am not sure how it works.

Comment: As a reference, you can look at our implementation of an RDBMS-based event store https://eventuous.dev/docs/infra/postgres/#data-model. There's a version for SQL Server too but it's not documented properly yet. You get the idea anyway. New event versions are recognised by type, and type is a string stored in that table. You don't need new tables for that.

Comment: I see...I don't think I've considered stream id that way before. I probably will need time to let this simmer in my head and figure out how it impacts everything (e.g. How I would project the RoomTypeAvailability read model efficiently if stream id is done that way, do I need to go through every event that might impact it, etc.). I'll take a look at the link you provided as well. Thanks for writing again, @AlexeyZimarev.